# Showing that $A=B$ iff $A \subseteq B$ and $A^c \subseteq B^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say we know that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ (it means that sets $A$, $B$ are the same).

The above is true if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $A^c \subseteq B^c$

How can we prove this?

We can forget about the $A \subseteq B$ part, we only need to show that $B \subseteq A$ iff $A^c \subseteq B^c$ (right?)

1. Let's say $B \subset A$. Then $A^c \subset B^c$, because complements invert their size. If $A=B$, it's obviously true that $A^c=B^c$. So we know that if $B \subseteq A$, then $A^c \subseteq B^c$.
2. Now we have to prove the implication in the other direction: if $A^c\subseteq B^c$, then $B \subseteq A$ (just like above).

Does my proof make sense? I think it's just too complicated, maybe you can suggest something shorter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that at this elementary level you need to carefully prove $A \subset B \Leftrightarrow A^c \subset B^c$ using the definition for $\subset : A \subset B$ iff $\forall x, x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$. Apart from this, your proof is a bit long because you repeat yourself many times.

Comment: I think you mean $A\subset B \iff B^c \subset A^c$?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_Complement_inverts_Subsets/Proof_1

Comment: Yes i wrote a bit too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that all you need to show is that $B\subseteq A$ if and only if $A^c\subseteq B^c.$ However, your "inverting size" approach does not work. Just because one set is smaller than another (in the sense of cardinality) doesn't mean it is a subset.

Rather, we would be better served to use "element-chasing." Start by assuming that $B\subseteq A,$ and take any $x\in A^c.$ This means in particular that $x\notin A.$ If we had $x\in B,$ then we would have $x\in A$ since $B\subseteq A,$ so we must have $x\notin B,$ and so $x\in B^c.$ Since $x\in A^c$ implies $x\in B^c,$ then $A^c\subseteq B^c.$ This proves one implication.

The other implication actually follows from this one, since $\left(A^c\right)^c=A$ and $\left(B^c\right)^c=B.$